# How to perform CRUD operations with specific user when using PHP Data Objects?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I have been following [this](https://www.develou.com/crear-un-webservice-para-android-con-mysql-php-y-json/) tutorial (in Spanish) to query a MySQL database from Android. The tutorial uses PHP web services (PDO). So far, queries are working, but I am using "root" user.

The app should allow users to make queries without login, but instead of using "root", I created "guest" user in the database to make these queries.

To insert, edit or deleted data, the users will need to login. For this, I created "admin" user. Of course, once the user is logged in as "admin", also can query the database with this user.

My problem is that this tutorial uses "root" for all operations.

**mysql_login.php:**

```
<?php
/**
 * Provee las constantes para conectarse a la base de datos
 * Mysql.
 */
define("HOSTNAME", "localhost");// Nombre del host
define("DATABASE", "i_wish"); // Nombre de la base de datos
define("USERNAME", "root"); // Nombre del usuario
define("PASSWORD", ""); // Nombre de la constraseña
?>
```

**Database.php:**

```
<?php
/**
 * Clase que envuelve una instancia de la clase PDO
 * para el manejo de la base de datos
 */

require_once 'mysql_login.php';


class Database
{

    /**
     * Única instancia de la clase
     */
    private static $db = null;

    /**
     * Instancia de PDO
     */
    private static $pdo;

    final private function __construct()
    {
        try {
            // Crear nueva conexión PDO
            self::getDb();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            // Manejo de excepciones
        }


    }

    /**
     * Retorna en la única instancia de la clase
     * @return Database|null
     */
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (self::$db === null) {
            self::$db = new self();
        }
        return self::$db;
    }

    /**
     * Crear una nueva conexión PDO basada
     * en los datos de conexión
     * @return PDO Objeto PDO
     */
    public function getDb()
    {
        if (self::$pdo == null) {
            self::$pdo = new PDO(
                'mysql:dbname=' . DATABASE .
                ';host=' . HOSTNAME .
                ';port:63343;',
                USERNAME,
                PASSWORD,
                array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")
            );

            // Habilitar excepciones
            self::$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }

        return self::$pdo;
    }

    /**
     * Evita la clonación del objeto
     */
    final protected function __clone()
    {
    }

    function _destructor()
    {
        self::$pdo = null;
    }
}

?>
```

I have found samples to have a login screen and validate the username and password such as: [this](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/connect_to_mysql) or [this](https://justsimpleinfo.blogspot.com/2018/06/android-simple-login-with-php-and-mysql.html).

However, what is not clear to me is what to do next. Once the user is validated, how do I make CRUD operations with my user? I am struggling to find a sample.

If I am not wrong, I think "mysql_login.php" should include the "guest" credentials, and not the "root" ones. Then, when the user tries to login from the app, I would have to query the database to validate the username and password. To do this, I should use "root", but how?

Do I need a second "Database.php" and "mysql_login.php" with "root" credentials? Because the first "Database.php" would contain "require_once 'mysql_login.php';" with "guest" credentials. Or is it possible to send these credentials from the app to the web service somehow? Like a parameter?

Second problem is that if user logins in successfully, then any CRUD query should be done with "admin" user. Not "guest", not "root". How to achieve this?

I guess that if it is possible to send the credentials via parameters for my first problem, then the solution to the second problem would be the same.

Thank you!

Comment: I think you are mixing database user authentication up with application authentication. Your application requires a mysql username and password to authenticate the database connection. Then it will compare the application user name and password parameters using sql queries in php.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavours from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](https://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files. Tutorials are not production-ready code.

Comment: Hi @Shadow, you are likely right and I am mixing things up. Regarding "it will compare the application user name and password parameters using sql queries in php". Can you provide more info? I am not sure how to do this. Shall I create a "users" table for this?

Comment: Hi @tadman, thank you for the advice, but this is not for production, this is an Android app I am developing because for the school, it is just a task we have to do. Because of this, I do not really want to learn a new technology from zero, just write the essential code for passing data between my app and my database. I found this tutorial and it works, but it does not contemplate multi-user apps, and my teache's requirement is to have 2 users. Hence I prefer to focus on how to fix, workaround or achieve this instead of looking at development frameworks right now.

Comment: Well, you have to store your application user names and passwords somewhere. If you want to use mysql for this, then you need to create a table. However, writing a login system is not straightforward and easy to get it wrong. I would suggest you to use some kind of a framework, as @tadman has already suggested, that implemented such a feature for you. Otherwise, there are lots of examples here on SO on implementing authentication. Be wary of any examples that do not hash passwords using password_hash() and password_verify() php functions.

Comment: If it's a school project, I would not use this pointless `Database` class. It adds complexity and provides no value. It's also a decade old, which is like learning to drive with a Ford-T. Instead, create your own instances of `PDO` and `PDOStatement` classes.

Answer (score -1):

- **Using Different Database Credentials**: Yes, you're correct that you should modify the mysql_login.php file to include the credentials for the "guest" user instead of the "root" user. You can then have another set of credentials for the "admin" user.
- **Handling User Authentication and Authorization**: After successfully validating the user's credentials, you can generate a token or session identifier on the server side to represent the authenticated user. This token can then be sent with each subsequent request from the app to identify the user and their permissions.
- **Differentiating User Permissions**: Once you have authenticated the user, you can maintain their role or permissions (e.g., "guest" or "admin") either in the session on the server side or in the token sent to the client. When the app makes CRUD operations, you can check the user's permissions before executing the database queries.

Modify mysql_login.php to include credentials for both "guest" and "admin" users.
Implement a login mechanism in your PHP web service to authenticate users. After successful authentication:
Generate a token representing the authenticated user and their permissions.
Send this token back to the app for future requests.
In each request from the app to the web service, include the token.
On the server side, validate the token and extract the user's permissions.
Before executing CRUD operations, check the user's permissions to ensure they are authorized to perform the requested action.

Comment: AI generated content is [currently banned](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/20153035) on Stack Overflow. Please read the [AI Policy](/help/ai-policy) for more information.